# Are Customer Created Custom Labels Visible in Managed Package Code

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, customlabel

Quick question, I couldn't find this in the documentation. If you have a managed package with managed class or code are custom created labels visible? For instance, in managed VF page if you had {!$Label[CustomCreateLabelName]} would that work or is it only possible to see labels in your managed code other than the labels packaged?

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: @RahulSharma Sorry, basically what I'm asking when you have a managed packaged and it is deployed to the customer. If you have reference to label that is dynamic, will labels created outside of the managed package (let's say the custom has their own label outside your package), will it be visible in your managed code. For instance, you have a VF page will you be able to reference their custom labels or only the ones in your managed package.

Comment: Ideally it should be possible, but Why would even you want to use it. Using custom settings or custom datatypes is recommended.

Comment: @RahulSharma Yeah, I don't want to use them. It was something that was already setup already. Basically, the customer wants something dynamic for headers and they needed translation. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that may be the cause of a page exception. My guess is that maybe that when VF looks for the custom label it may only see the packaged labels and thus throw an exception (a 500 error). This only happens in the managed packaged environment.